# Any (opensource) tool that we can use to detect if our computers has been installed applications that have proxies services

Tags: antivirus, proxy, detection, http-proxy

Read something like this on reddit "someone can also be a regular user who does not read terms and conditions of apps that they install. Some apps might include code that will enable them to run trafic through their IP while the app is on. "  Does that mean someone install applications that take advantage of non-technical users using their IP to do anything that they want?

Is this case is it a virus? but still any tool to detect those apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A packet capture tool will be able to show when traffic is going to strange places and at strange times and volumes. Wireshark is the common tool for this type of thing.